# How to run Git projects on SDD (non Root)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, git

So I have a dual boot partition Windows/Ubuntu and I code in the Ubuntu OS. I have all my projects under the HDD but it's getting full and I would like to pass them onto the SSD (where I have loads of space). O created a virtual link in the HDD to quickly access the projects I copied to the SSD but since it is not a root directory I can't seem to be able to do anything.

Comment: On which disk you have Windows, and on which Ubuntu? It is not clear what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the Windows storage from Ubuntu itself. You can access your windows storage drives & its files from Files -> Other Locations -> Select the appropriate drive. Make sure you do this as a root user.